# How to send BSC transaction with golang

Tags: go, ethereum, go-ethereum, binance-smart-chain, bsc

I have a Smart Chain wallet which i want to send a token or BSC from it to another address programmatically using Go.

I tried [go-ethereum](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum) library and [bnb-chain](https://github.com/bnb-chain/bsc) but i can't figure out how to do this.

Note: i don't want to run a full/light node to solve this. any help?